# my pages_messaging_subscriptions is not approved by facebook for Food & Gift ordering chatbot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have developed chatbot for Food & Gift ordering from chat. I have applied for pages_messaging_subscriptions for apps.

Why I need that permission: User place order via chat. We need to send confirmation back to users. Sometimes, we need to give confirmation to user after 24 hours in case of Gift shop.

I have applied it under "News" category. But FB has not approved that permission.

FB:

> Your Messenger experience does not fall into the news use case that
>   you submitted for. Please review eligible use cases for
>   subscription-based messaging in our Messenger Policy Overview.

Can Anyone guide me how can I get that permission for my chatbot?

Thanks

Comment: Of course that isn’t “News”. And I doubt they’d accept it as “Productivity” either … you can try, of course, but if what you want to send doesn’t fall into any of the three categories (by their definition), then there is no way.

Comment: @CBroe: I had tried with Productivity as well.But no success.

Answer (score 0):

This is not 100% solution, just an idea.

I have the same issue with my https://www.refurbishedbot.com, tried News and Productivity categories with no success. What my bot does - user subscribes to some Apple device, like iPhone 6s Plus, and when new deal appears on Apple website user gets notification and purchases iPhone from the Apple website.

My idea how to obtain `pages_messaging_subscriptions` permission approved is to implement some real News from Apple website by consuming their feed and provide content for users. Hopefully this will get some success.